# on hover for icon-caret-down

Tags: css, icons

Is it possible to add onhover effect to icon-caret-down? I used the css for icon-caret down. My code is as follows:

```
.icon-caret-down:before{
  content:"\f0d7";
  font-family:'fontawesome-alloy';
  speak:none;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-variant:normal;
  text-transform:none;
  line-height:1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  margin-top: 0; 
}
```

To add some effect on hover i tried but did not work

```
.icon-caret-down:before:hover{
    color:red;
 }
```

HTML is:

```
<span id="idofspan" onclick="somefun()"><i class="icon-caret-down"></i></span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `:before` it doesn't seem relevant. Simply add `:hover`

```
.icon-caret-down:before{
  content:"▼";
  font-family:'arial';
  speak:none;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-variant:normal;
  text-transform:none;
  line-height:1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  margin-top: 0; 
}
.icon-caret-down:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

---

### CLICK FOR DEMO

---

To hover when using `:before` use `:hover:before`

```
.icon-caret-down:before {
    content:"\f0d7";
    font-family:'fontawesome-alloy';
    speak:none;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-transform:none;
    line-height:1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top: 0; 
    cursor:pointer;background:#27a7eb; color: #FFF; border-radius:50%; font-size:14px; height:auto;margin-left:5px;padding: 1px 4px; width:auto;
}
.icon-caret-down:hover:before {
    background:#b00;
}
```

---

### CLICK FOR DEMO

---

Comment: Thank you ! your code is working. Actually i forget to mention that i also have an outer circle for the arrow and that must be the reason why the effect was not visible..is it possible to change the background color of that circle from blue to something else? JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7w5edkyh/2/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `:before` pseudo-selector there:

```
.icon-caret-down:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The code you suggested is working but i also have a circle outside that arrow and because of that the on hover effect is not working. Can you suggest how can i make the hover effect visible:

Answer (score 0):

Put the "before" pseudo tag *after* the hover if you want just the icon to change:

```
.icon-caret-down:hover:before{
    color:red;
}
```

If you want the entire item to change, simply remove the **:before**

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkatect/2zm77zrd/)

Answer (score 0):

To enable on hover in css use

```
.icon-caret-down:hover{
color:red;

}
```

Note :before is a selector for more go to

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before_style